# How to implement live streaming in a WordPress website?

Tags: wordpress

We've developed a baby monitor and we want to implment live streaming in our website so the parents can monitor the live recording.

The website front end is designed in WordPress but I don't know how to implement this. Please inform if there is any easiest way to implment it.

Finding a solution or getting guideline